# Find number in div of given class, and hide/display div based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a request that goes beyond my very basic scripting abilities.  I have a website with a message that tells users how many days they have left until their password expires:

"John doe's password expires in 91 days"

I'd like to add some script that evaluates this statement, which is contained in a div of class "expiryNotice," extract the number, and basically hide the entire div if greater than 60.

I've written JS/jQuery to do static modifications before, but never anything with any kind of logic, so I am a bit lost with where to begin.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where's your code?!

Comment: Didn't know where to begin, so figured I shouldn't litter OP with pathetic attempts.

Comment: You need to show your markup for the current "Expiry notice" section, and then people can help you. If you don't this question is unanswerable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat, there are probably more reasonable ways to go about this than parsing the text in the message div, but this will do it:

```js
$(function(){
  var msg = $('#notice').text()
  var days = msg.match(/\d+/)[0]
  console.log(days)
  if(Number(days) > 60) {
    $('#notice').hide()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notice">"John doe's password expires in 91 days"</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function CheckExpiryNotice(maxNum) {
  var expiryNoticeDiv = $('.expiryNotice');
  var expiryNoticeStr = expiryNoticeDiv.text();
  $(expiryNoticeStr.split(" ")).each(function(i,e) {
    if($.isNumeric(e)) { 
      if(e > maxNum) {
       expiryNoticeDiv.hide();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Calling this function should work `CheckExpiryNotice(60);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in javascript, if you don't want to use jQuery:

```
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('expiryNotice');
    var str = elem[0].innerText;
    var days = str.match(/\d+/)[0];
    if (+days > 60) {
        elem[0].hidden = true;
    }
```